# How to add entries in Application.conf during runtime?

Tags: caching, playframework, redis, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

How to add separate redis cache instances at runtime?

Manually one can add multiple redis cache instances in this way

**Application.conf:**

```
redis.uri="redis://192.168.3.170:6000"

# disable default Play framework cache plugin
play.modules.disabled = ["play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"]

# enable redis cache module
#play.modules.enabled = ["play.api.cache.redis.RedisCacheModule"]

#Multiple redis caches
play.cache.redis.bindCaches = ["cache1","cache2","cache3"]
```

How if I need to add one more cache say *cache4* during runtime?

I have tried through `ConfigFactory.load.entrySet()` and `Config` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it since `Config` is immutable. Also, keep in mind that your redis cache implementation would need to listen to configuration changes in order to recognize the new cache.

Maybe a better way is to have this built into Redis module. In other words, you would be able to do something like `redis.addCache("cache4")`.